# A recursive function that prints the partitions of N into K numbers

Tags: c, recursion, backtracking

I am supposed to write a recursive operation that receives 2 parameters, N and K, and prints all the partitions of N into a sum of K non-negative integers.
N is the sum, and
K is the number of summands in each partition,
So for example if I get N=5, K=3, then
my recursion should print for me at the end:

```
5 0 0

4 1 0 

3 2 0

3 1 1

2 2 1
```

my code:

```
  void f(int a, int k, int secondArray[], int used)
{
    
    if (k <= 0 && a <= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", secondArray[i]);

        }
        puts("\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = (used >0)? min(secondArray[used-1],a):a; i >=0; i--)
    {
        secondArray[used] = i;
        f(a - i, k - 1, secondArray, used + 1);
    }
}
```

My code is printing only the 2 lines, but does not work for anything else.

Comment: These are called [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), not variations. You want to list the partitions of N into K non-negative integer summands (equivalently, into K or fewer positive integer summands).

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Please take some time to read or refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You're right, Im sorry.

Comment: There is no question in your post. Edit it to ask a specific question. Include a [mre] if appropriate.

Comment: Hey guys, edit my code + my question, ♥

Comment: There is no question in your post. Things posted as questions to Stack Overflow should ask a specific question. There is also no [mre] in your post. A [mre] for a non-working program contains at least a `main` function. It should have everything readers need to compile and run the the program without having to make any edits, including adding any lines like `#include <stdio.h>`. You need to show how `f` is called, and you need to explain what the arguments are for. Add comments to the code explaining what you are trying to do with it…

Comment: … If people cannot figure out what your code is supposed to do, they cannot tell what is wrong with the design. Your question says the program is given an “N” and a “K”, but the function has parameters “a”, “k”, “secondArray”, and “used”. There is no “N”, and “k” is different from “K”. What is a caller supposed to pass to this function?

Comment: I am too lazy to debug your program. But some advice is: run it with a smaller N and k. Determine the smallest N and k for which it produces incorrect output, and debug that case. Debugging recursive functions can be confusing, so working on a small test-case will save much time and frustration.